# Fluent Validator missing SetCollectionValidator() method

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation

I'm new to **Fluent Validation** and just got the **version 5.3** from nu Get yesterday. I'm trying to apply an existing validator (PhoneValidator) to a collection property (ICollection) of a class (Employee). The Fluent Validator documentation says to use:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Orders).SetCollectionValidator(new OrderValidator()); // example usage
```

However the **SetCollectionValidator()** method is not available on the version I have. Instead there is only **SetValidator()** which is marked as **[deprecated]**. I've seen other posts regarding this same situation and have learned that SetCollectionValidator() is an extension method and need to be sure I have FluentValidation imported. I do.

What am I missing here?

```
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.Validators;

public class EmployeeValidator : AbstractValidator<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeValidator()
    {            
        // SetCollectionValidator doesn't show in intellisense and won't compile
        RuleFor(e => e.PhoneNumbers).SetCollectionValidator(new PhoneValidator()); 
    }
}

public class PhoneValidator : AbstractValidator<Phone>
{
    public PhoneValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(e => e.Number).Length(10).Matches("^[0-9]$");            
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add your Employee class (or at least the type of PhoneNumbers property in Employee class)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm late to the party but it was the first hit on Google so I thought it'd help others. It seems the API has changed, you now need to do:

```cs
RuleForEach(e => e.PhoneNumbers).SetValidator(new PhoneValidator());
```

A bit nicer in my opinion.